# How to create a calculated field that calls the same calculated field in MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, circular-reference, calculated-field, cumulative-sum

I am creating a Access database query from an excel spreedsheet where the row "Total Capital Calls" is calculated by itself and "Current Capital Call", which is static.

The data from the spreedsheet:

```
                                 A          B           C           D
```

1 Current Capital Call                              1,000,000       240,000           2,000,000         1,960,000

2 Total Capital Calls                                     1,000,000     1,240,000        3,240,000       5,200,000

The calculation is as follows:

```
                                 A          B           C           D
```

1 Current Capital Call                          1,000,000        240,000              2,000,000       1,960,000

2 Total Capital Calls                             1,000,000       =+B1+A2           =+C1+B2          =+D1+C2

So the formula is repeated as data moves to the next Total Capital Call field, summing the total to the next 'Total Capital Call' field.

I am trying to create a calculated field in a query using the same calculated field name in the calculation. I need the calculated field "Total Capital Calls" to sum itself with the field [Current Capital Call].

For example:

```
SELECT LlamadoDeCapital.[Total Capital Committed], 
    LlamadoDeCapital.[Capital Call Request Date], 
    LlamadoDeCapital.[Capital Call Date], 
    LlamadoDeCapital.[Current Capital Call], 
    [Current Capital Call]+[Total Capital Calls] 
AS [Total Capital Calls]
FROM LlamadoDeCapital;
```

After running the query, I get this message:

`Circular reference caused by alias 'Total Capital Calls' in query definition's SELECT list`

Is it possible to call the calculated field in it's own expression??

or

Is there better solution to summing the calculated field with itself and the other field?

Comment: Read [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/210504)

Comment: Is your table structured like it's shown?  you have multiple fields accross instead of records down?  if the latter.. You're basically looking for a running sum?  Is this for a report or for a form?  Take a look at this link:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290136

Comment: Thank you both of your recommendations. I may have to use both the DLookup and DSum functions together somehow, but I am not quite sure how. At the moment, I am try to get the DSum function working only with the "Current Capital Calls" field to prove that works, however, I am getting a syntax error.

Comment: Here is my Select Expression: SELECT LlamadoDeCapital.ID, LlamadoDeCapital.[TotalCapitalCommitted], LlamadoDeCapital.[CapitalCallRequestDate], LlamadoDeCapital.[CapitalCallDate], LlamadoDeCapital.[CurrentCapitalCall]
DSum("CurrentCapitalCall","LlamadoDeCapital","CapitalCallDate <=" & [CapitalCallDate]) AS TotalCapitalCalls
FROM LlamadoDeCapital;

Comment: Here is the error I'm getting: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'LlamadoDeCapital.[CurrentCapitalCall]
DSum("CurrentCapitalCall","LlamadoDeCapital","CapitalCallDate" <=" & [CapitalCallDate])'.

Comment: Ok, was able to resolve the syntax error. I replaced the commas with semi colons. But now when the query is run, nothing is summed in the "TotalCapitalCalls" column.

Comment: My updated expression. Only semi-colons were changed: SELECT LlamadoDeCapital.ID, LlamadoDeCapital.TotalCapitalCommitted, LlamadoDeCapital.CapitalCallRequestDate, LlamadoDeCapital.CapitalCallDate, LlamadoDeCapital.CurrentCapitalCall, DSum("CurrentCapitalCall","LlamadoDeCapital","CapitalCallDate <=" & [CapitalCallDate]) AS TotalCapitalCalls
FROM LlamadoDeCapital;

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so adding the clng function was the resolution:

DSum("CurrentCapitalCall","LlamadoDeCapital","CapitalCallDate <=" & **clng(**[CapitalCallDate]**)**) AS TotalCapitalCalls

Running Sum total with both fields.